# How to include or bootstrap the paypal-core-sdk php

Tags: php, paypal, sdk, include

I've downloaded the paypal-core-sdk for php from GitHub manually, my server does not have 'composer' and I've just manually copied the files to an include directory outside the document root.   Problem is when I go call on some of the classes the server borks and doesn't know what I'm talking about ... i.e.

```
Fatal error: Class 'PPApiContext' not found in /home/rctoronto/public_html/start.php on line 143
```

if I include once on the file providing PPApiContext, it moves along to another error and so on eventually proceeds when I've included all the ones it complains about.  But then the sdk has internal dependency issues.

How do I formally declare the sdk library so my app can use it - I've scoured the web and haven't managed to find a good answer to this question.  I've tried manually altering my include_path using my php.ini and still it can't use the classes of the sdk.   I don't have access to /usr/lib/php or /usr/local/lib/php as I am on a shared server.

this is the 'getAuthorize' url for paypal (which I've gotten to work with manually include_once on the files...

```
$apicontext = new PPApiContext(array('mode' => 'live'));
$clientId = PP_CLIENTID;
$clientSecret = PP_SECRET;
$scope = array('openid', 'email'); 
$redirectUri = 'https://maskedurl.ca/login?ltype=pp&loginSubmit=true';
$pp_authUrl = PPOpenIdSession::getAuthorizationUrl($redirectUri, $scope , $clientId,       $apicontext);
```

But how do we properly declare the sdk library in whole?

Comment: https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-php is the library I am trying to use..

Comment: I just did it the hard way, with trial and error. I'm surprised there's not an overall 'include' file.

Comment: I actually ended up abandoning the PHP SDK and used the cURL examples to implement the solution...

Comment: Hi Ryan, Did you overcome with the problem? I am facing the same problem with PHP SDK.

Answer (score 5):

From: http://paypal.github.io/sdk/

> If you do not want to use composer, you can grab the SDK zip, unzip the file to your application folder and require the 'vendor/autoload.php' file. This file registers a custom autoloader that can autload the PayPal SDK files.

[Download SDK zip](https://github.com/paypal/sdk-packages/raw/gh-pages/rest-api-sdk/php/rest-api-sdk-php-0.7.1.zip)

Comment: Thanks :)  good answer! (I don't have enough reputation points to up vote it) I'm sure others with a similar issue will also find it useful.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I solved it.  Update composer.json as follows:

```
{
    "name": "PayPal Test",
    "require": {
        "paypal/sdk-core-php": "dev-stable"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {"PayPal\\": "vendor/paypal/sdk-core-php/lib/"}
    }    
}
```

Comment: I didn't try your solution as I abandoned the SDK temporarily in favour of just doing CURL calls within PHP myself.  I will try it out when I can allocate some time again for this and score you a +1 if it works ;)

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job:

```
include('paypal-sdk-core/lib/common/PPApiContext.php');
include('paypal-sdk-core/lib/PPConstants.php');
include('paypal-sdk-core/lib/PPConfigManager.php');
include('paypal-sdk-core/lib/auth/openid/PPOpenIdSession.php');
```

If you need the full stack to make the example on https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/openid/php?interactive=ON&env=sandbox work, use this:

```
include('paypal-sdk-core/lib/common/PPApiContext.php');
include('paypal-sdk-core/lib/PPHttpConfig.php');
include('paypal-sdk-core/lib/common/PPUserAgent.php');
include('paypal-sdk-core/lib/PPHttpConnection.php');
include('paypal-sdk-core/lib/PPLoggingLevel.php');
include('paypal-sdk-core/lib/exceptions/PPConnectionException.php');
include('paypal-sdk-core/lib/common/PPModel.php');
include('paypal-sdk-core/lib/auth/IPPThirdPartyAuthorization.php');
include('paypal-sdk-core/lib/handlers/IPPHandler.php');
include('paypal-sdk-core/lib/PPConstants.php');
include('paypal-sdk-core/lib/PPConfigManager.php');
include('paypal-sdk-core/lib/auth/openid/PPOpenIdSession.php');
include('paypal-sdk-core/lib/auth/PPTokenAuthorization.php');
include('paypal-sdk-core/lib/auth/openid/PPOpenIdTokeninfo.php');
include('paypal-sdk-core/lib/transport/PPRestCall.php');
include('paypal-sdk-core/lib/PPLoggingManager.php');
include('paypal-sdk-core/lib/handlers/PPOpenIdHandler.php');
```