# Include PayPal SDK PHP

Tags: php, paypal, composer-php

I am trying to use the paypal php sdk that I downloaded from github at this link: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK. I saved the project in the correct directory on my web server. What file do I need to include so that I can use the libraries? Composer is not installed on my hosting, so I would prefer to just include the library with the require statement. The API docs are located here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include or bootstrap the paypal-core-sdk php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21494791/how-to-include-or-bootstrap-the-paypal-core-sdk-php)

Comment: StackOverflow is for specific coding questions, not so much product support or getting-started content.  You should probably direct this question to whomever supports the PayPal SDK.  Perhaps they have a new-user tutorial.  If after going through the tutorial, you have a specific problem or question, you can post code and ask about it here on SO.

Comment: What you need is to look at the wiki documentation : https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki to get all answers on how to setup, and make it work with your code.

Answer (score 0):

There would be no setup files required. All the libararies are included in your downloaded SDK.

Run the `PayPal-PHP-SDK/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/sample/index.php` from your project root directory.

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/sample/README.md